# Measuring the absolute position of a series of DOM elements in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/8292lmypz2

I'm trying to measure the absolute position some `div`s. I'm accessing the DOM node of the `div` through a forwarded `ref` (`React.forwardRef()`) to the div I'm interested in. In the constructor of my parent component, I'm populating an array with `React.createRef()`s, which I then assign to each divs ref iteratively as they're being rendered. Finally, I log the return value of `getBoundingClientRect()` for each div. The problem is that - in spite of the fact that each div has a unique position relative to the next one - the same data is returned every single time. It's as if I was getting the `getBoundingClientRect()` data for the same div eight times. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic issue in your case is that in order to create the array of refs, you are using `Array.fill` method, which initialises all the values in the array with the same reference of the `React.createRef`, and hence when you try `assign refs` to the divs, all ref properties will refer to the last div being assigned the ref instance

A simple way to fix this is to use Map instead of fill like

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.refArray = Array.apply(null, { length: props.number.length}).map(() => React.createRef());
  }
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ypy0k51vpx)**

Comment: Thanks a million! Completely misunderstood the mechanism behind `Array.fill`.

Comment: Glad to have helped :-). It happens generally. Fill should be used to initialise arrays with immutable values like numbers, strings, boolean and not mutable values like arrays and objects